# How do I install the latest BioPerl version when using perlbrew?

Tags: perl, git, cpan, perlbrew, bioperl

I'm using `perlbrew` and I would like to install the latest bioperl version. Should I use `cpanm` or `git`?

If `git` - do I just install as usual (AKA `git clone ...` then make and build), or should I do anything special?

**UPDATE**

Specifically, I'm not sure I understand the following expert from [BioPerl Using Git manual](http://www.bioperl.org/wiki/Using_Git):

> Tell perl where to find BioPerl
>   (assuming you checked out the code in
>   $HOME/src; set this in your
>   .bash_profile, .profile, or .cshrc):
>
> ```
> bash: $ export PERL5LIB="$HOME/src/bioperl-live:$PERL5LIB"
> tcsh: $ setenv PERL5LIB "$HOME/src/bioperl-live:$PERL5LIB"
> ```

Why is this necesary?

**UPDATE 2**

Simply exporting the bioperl cloned dir does not effect all the `bp_***.pl` scripts (which are usually found under `/usr/bin/` after a normal `Build` installation).

I also tried to build from the cloned dir after switching to the correct perl version using `perlbrerw`, but then it runs cpan shell to install some dependencies which does not seem to work well with `perlbrew` (as opposed to `cpanm`).

So, my question remains...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest [BioPerl](http://www.bioperl.org/wiki/Main_Page) is always going to be on [GitHub](http://github.com/bioperl), so git's your answer there. Whether or not you want bleeding edge is another story, but after following the BioPerl mailing list for some time I get the feeling that the developers are more likely to say "[install from GitHub](http://www.bioperl.org/wiki/Using_Git)" if you have any problems with BioPerl, especially since the [most recent version on CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/dist/BioPerl/) is from 2009. There has been a lot of development since then.

As for installing it, I don't see why you couldn't just go ahead and do the standard `git clone ...` make/build dance once you're using your `perlbrew` perl, as that's kind of the point of `perlbrew`. :-)

**Update for question update:** The blurb about setting `PERL5LIB` is there because presumably BioPerl doesn't need to be built once you've cloned it via `git`; it's ready to use straight out of the box. Assuming you haven't cloned it into a directory in `@LIB`, you need to tell Perl where to find it. You would have to do this whether or not you are using `perlbrew`.

Essentially the process goes like this:

1. Clone BioPerl from GitHub.
2. Make sure you're using your `perlbrew`-installed Perl.
3. Set the `PERL5LIB` environment variable as per the BioPerl instructions.
4. Run `perl -MBio::Perl -le 'print Bio::Perl->VERSION;'` to make sure you're using the BioPerl you just checked out.

Looking at [the sourcecode](http://github.com/bioperl/bioperl-live/blob/master/Bio/Root/Version.pm), #4 should print out 1.006900, I think (or maybe 1.6.9, I can never keep Perl version numbers straight).

Comment: No build? But bioperl has all the `bp_***` scripts which are globally accessible. Will they be updated? How can they become accessible at the first place if no install was done?

Comment: I can't say for certain, but I think if you get the `bioperl-run` package from GitHub you could set your `PATH` environment variable to wherever it puts the `bp_*` programs.

Comment: Getting the version on CPAN updated is another problem, which I'm sure would be greatly appreciated by the community if someone took on this task.